# Elm Style-Elements dropMenu does not update view until selection loses focus

Tags: elm, elm-style-elements

Full code is here on ellie: https://ellie-app.com/hC86PYBMda1/0

The issue is that while the model field targeted by the menu updates on selection, the full effect of the `Msg` sent to update is not executed until either `CloseMenu` or another `OpenMenu` `SelectMsg` is sent.

The relevant portion of the update function:

```
update msg model =
  case msg of
    SelectBenzo searchMsg ->
      (benzoUpdate searchMsg model, Cmd.none)
    ...
```

which calls the following function:

```
benzoUpdate searchMsg ({meds} as model) =
  { model | meds = { meds | benzo = Input.updateSelection searchMsg meds.benzo }
, selectedMed = case Input.selected meds.benzo of
    Nothing -> NoneChosen
    Just benzo -> Stage1 benzo
} |> updateCurrentMedDose

updateCurrentMedDose model = { model | dose = (dosing (Maybe.withDefault 0 model.ptWt) model.selectedMed) }
```

Comment: advice on either accessing the isOpen field of the SelectMenu (which updates without a CloseMenu message) or configuring the onUpdate field (which currently just shows XXX) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a known issue with style elements around this sort of thing. I think that is why the keyed library is exposed. Try using this instead of the element directly.

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/style-elements/4.3.0/Element-Keyed

Comment: using Element.Keyed in the column wrapping the menu does not seem to fix the issue.  Does the String in the (String, Element ...) tuple need to be anything specific like the model field or something?

Comment: you might have better luck in the slack Style-Elements channel :/ sorry